# Rails 3.2 and thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thin

I am using Rails 3.2 and Thin server, but the latter does not start. Well... it starts but stops immediately

```
rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting
```

Gem 'thin' is in Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was using the faye-rails and thin gem and had a route for faye in the `config/routes.rb` file. I took the route out and thin started without exiting.