# Rails server exits immediately (thin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

`rails s` causes the server to exit immediately. Contrary to other posts I have found, I get no error code. The logs are:

```
Resque::Helpers will be gone with no replacement in Resque 2.0.0.
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:62932, CTRL+C to stop
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting
```

I am using Rails 4.0.0

Comment: have you tried without thin?

Comment: If you look in `log/development.log`, is there any error?

Comment: no. I don't know what thin is (well I've just found that it is a ruby server. It seems to be related to nginx that I am using) How can I start ruby without thin?

Comment: in `log/development.log` I just have two lines for ActiveRecord schema migrations:
    ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
    ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY version

Comment: Does your Gemfile have `gem 'thin'`? If you remove that, it should run on WEBrick instead.

Comment: no the Gemfile doesn't have `gem 'thin'` but the Gemfile.lock has it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

['rails server' starts thin twice, shuts both down. Cucumber still works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733117/rails-server-starts-thin-twice-shuts-both-down-cucumber-still-works)   ... In your case delete the gemfile.lock and run another bundle install.